# How to give a good upper bound on tail probability for $P\{|\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}-1| \ge \varepsilon\}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of i.i.d. standard normal random variables. $R_n=\sqrt{X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2)}$.

How could I prove $P\{|\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}-1| \ge  \varepsilon\}=O(\frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}}) $?

If so, I could prove $R_n/\sqrt{n} \rightarrow_p1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(X_i)$ are independent. Thus, $(X_i^2)$ are independent. So, by the Weak Law of Large Numbers (check conditions)

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2\rightarrow^p EX_1^2=1$$
Then the continuous mapping theorem implies your result.

---

**Edit:** You can use Chebyshev's ineq. instead:

$$P(|\frac{R_n^2}{n}-1|>\epsilon)\le\frac{Var(X_1^2)}{n\epsilon^2}\rightarrow 0$$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$.