# Show almost everywhere convergence for variable with Chi distribution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers, almost-everywhere

Setting

$$X_1,X_2,\ldots \overset{d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$R_n = \sqrt{X_1^2 + \ldots + X_n^2}$$

I would like to show $\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 1$ almost everywhere. I have tried to set it up using Borel-Cantelli lemma, where by forming the event
$$A_n = \left\{\left|\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}} - 1\right| \ge \epsilon \right\}$$

I would show the series
$$\sum_{n} \Pr\{A_n\} < \infty$$

and conclude $\Pr\{ A_n, ~i.o.\} = 0$.

So I require $\Pr\{A_n\} \rightarrow 0$ for suitably large $n$. However, I am not sure how to show

$$Pr\left\{\left|\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}} - 1\right| \ge \epsilon \right\} \rightarrow 0$$

My problems are

1. expected value of $\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is 1 in the limiting case only, so what tools can I use here to put a bound on the probability?
2. I tried taking the fourth moment of $\frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}} - 1$, but it is not looking good for convergence.

Some directions, both conceptual and relating to algebra would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The same question is here (just replace convergence in prob. to a.s.) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058622/how-to-give-a-good-upper-bound-on-tail-probability-for-p-fracr-n-sqrtn/1058654#1058654

Comment: The answer to that problem proves Pr{An} goes to 0, but I would like some 1/poly(n) upper bound for all values of P{An} at each n, so I can prove the series converges. It's funny since the question is asking for the same bound, but no answer was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X_i)$ are independent, $(X_i^2)$ are also independent. So, by the Strong Law of Large Numbers (check conditions)

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2\rightarrow^{a.s.} EX_1^2=1$$
Then the continuous mapping theorem implies your result (As pointed by @NateEldredge, continuity is enough here)

Comment: Since we're dealing with a.s. convergence here rather than i.p., we don't really need the continuous mapping theorem, just the definition of continuity.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank's. Good point.